# How to change font size in table of content

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, table-of-contents

How can i change the font size of layers in the TOC manualy and also with arcpy ?  The default is to small

Comment: Would you elaborate the question a bit in. It will be better to understand the question and for those who trying to be your helper (e.g. do you mean label font, what is the version of your arc map)--thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to change the font size of the text (such as layers name) in the Table of Contents in ArcGIS. You cannot do this manually or with ArcPy. It might be possible to do with ArcObjects, but it would involve heavy development effort.

Your option is to use Windows settings:

Go to Start > Control Panel > Personalization > Window Color and then choose Icon. In the lower panel choose Font Size. This is the option that controls the font of the name of the layers in the ArcMap TOC.

[image]

Comment: Yes Impossible -https://geonet.esri.com/thread/49491

Comment: nothing happeneD.the font didn't changed